# Recent algorithms for correcting mislabeled data using multilayer perceptrons

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, papers, multilayer-perceptrons, multi-label-classification

I am doing literature research on algorithms for correcting mislabeled data using multilayer perceptrons. Found an "old" paper [An algorithm for correcting mislabeled data](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3a09/c6f3873dd0327a3f9d83b7ff1c8b43a06cc3.pdf) (2001) by Xinchuan Zeng et al. Please share if you are aware of recent/current updates with a brief thoughts. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you just looking for techniques that specifically use MLPs or any other technique for correcting mislabelled data?

Comment: I have numerical data with "unrelated" columns of numbers. Therefore, I think MLPs make more sense rather than, for example, CNNs.

Comment: I am also not sure if https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.08019 and https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/6413805 will be more powerful as compared to MLPs.

Answer (score 1):

The most general solution today for the problem of finding label errors in datasets is called "confident learning" which works for all datasets and models, can be run time-efficiently [in one line of code using cleanlab](https://github.com/cleanlab/cleanlab), and has substantial theory to prove that it works in realistic conditions on real-world datasets. This "confident learning" paper was a culminating result during my PhD at MIT and I am an author on the paper.

- The Confident Learning Paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.00068
- Code: https://github.com/cleanlab/cleanlab
- Examples of label errors found with cleanlab: https://labelerrors.com

### Find label issues in your dataset in 1 line of code

```
from cleanlab.classification import CleanLearning
from cleanlab.filter import find_label_issues

# Option 1 - works with sklearn-compatible models - just input the data and labels ツ
label_issues_info = CleanLearning(clf=sklearn_compatible_model).find_label_issues(data, labels)

# Option 2 - works with ANY ML model - just input the model's predicted probabilities
ordered_label_issues = find_label_issues(
    labels=labels,
    pred_probs=pred_probs,  # out-of-sample predicted probabilities from any model
    return_indices_ranked_by='self_confidence',
)
```

### Train a model as if the dataset did not have errors -- 3 lines of code

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from cleanlab.classification import CleanLearning

cl = CleanLearning(clf=LogisticRegression())  # any sklearn-compatible classifier
cl.fit(train_data, labels)

# Estimate the predictions you would have gotten if you trained without mislabeled data.
predictions = cl.predict(test_data)
```

Documentation and runnable tutorials for cleanlab: https://docs.cleanlab.ai/

### The above approaches find issues. To correct label issues in your dataset:

The above approaches, just find issues and train without them. To correct the labels or train a model on a corrected dataset (that still includes all the errors, but now corrected with the right label), there is a no-code tool for that called [Cleanlab Studio](https://cleanlab.ai/studio) (https://cleanlab.ai/studio) for which I am also an author.

### Background if you're interested:

I spent half a decade working with [Isaac Chuang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Chuang) (inventor of the quantum computer) to solve this problem in a way that works for every dataset and every model (and every future dataset and future model) during my PhD at MIT. I originally decided to solve this problem after discovering (while building MIT and Harvard's cheating detection system in 2013) that most real-world datasets have significant label errors and this is one of the biggest problems that companies and universities struggle with when training ML models.